# How to speed up ethreum transaction after initiating

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs

Is there any possibility to speed up transaction after creating transaction receipt. 
My project need to similar functionality we have with metamask is there a way we can accomplish this using any javascript libraries like web3 etherjs  ?[image]

Comment: The only way to do that is by setting a higher gas-price (before submitting the transaction).

Comment: for that we already have option , this is something i need to build similarly metmask is doing like "speedup" button in image

Comment: And what exactly do you think that SpeedUp button does?

Comment: speed up button will increase gas price to existing transaction , I don't know how they are accomplished it.  - Setting higher gas fee before initiating transaction simplest way to get confirmation, but I need to implement a feature which can speed up transaction after initiating transfer

Comment: They override the pending transaction by sending a new one using the same nonce but a higher gas-price. You can do the same.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration this is could be the possible solution